# Component Development / Different Designer vs. Runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to create my own compoment.
 1. FAMPanel => TPanel-> OK.

```
unit famui;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type

  CorporateDesign = record
    white: TColor;
    black: TColor;
    gray: TColor;
    darkgray: TColor;
    blue: TColor;
    blueLight: TColor;
    red: TColor;
    font: String;
  end;

  FAMPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  protected
    { Protected-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published-Deklarationen }
  end;

const
  _CorporateDesign: CorporateDesign = (white: clWhite; black: clBlack;
    gray: $00F8F8F8; darkgray: $00E5E5E5; blue: $00D37C00; blueLight: $00E9BE80;
    red: $001619DA; font: 'Roboto Light');

implementation

{ FAMPanel }

constructor FAMPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  self.BevelInner := bvNone;
  self.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  self.Color := _CorporateDesign.white;
  self.font.Name := _CorporateDesign.font;
end;

destructor FAMPanel.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

end.
```

2. FAMCard => FAMPanel -> OK.
 2.1 Add 3 Panels (FAMPanel) to (FAMCard) -> OK

```
unit card;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, famui;

type

  FAMCard = class(FAMPanel)
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    Header: FAMPanel;
    Content: FAMPanel;
    Footer: FAMPanel;
  protected
    { Protected-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published-Deklarationen }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('FAMUI', [FAMCard]);
end;

{ TFamGUI }

constructor FAMCard.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  // Default size of fam card
  self.Width := 600;
  self.Height := 400;

  // Create header of card
  Header := FAMPanel.Create(self);
  Header.Parent := self;
  Header.Color := _CorporateDesign.gray;
  Header.Align := alTop;
  Header.Height := 90;

  // Create content of card
  Content := FAMPanel.Create(self);
  Content.Parent := self;
  Content.Color := _CorporateDesign.white;
  Content.Align := alClient;

  // Create footer of card
  Footer := FAMPanel.Create(self);
  Footer.Parent := self;
  Footer.Color := _CorporateDesign.gray;
  Footer.Align := alBottom;
  Footer.Height := 90;

end;

destructor FAMCard.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;

end;

end.
```

4. New Project / Component in designer  -> OK
   [image]
5. After compile -> Error, Header Content and Footer area are hidden (display:none)
   [image]

Why?

Answer (score 0):

FAMPanel is derived from TPanel. TPanel.ParentBackground has a default value of True which prevents your code from setting the Color property in a themed environment.

The fix is easy, just add to FAMPanel.Constructor the marked line:

```
constructor FAMPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  self.BevelInner := bvNone;
  self.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  self.ParentBackground := False;  // Add this line
  self.Color := _CorporateDesign.white;
  self.font.Name := _CorporateDesign.font;
end;
```